# Printing using PDFrenderer to print pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a pdf file using the pdfrenderer library. For that, it is required to convert the actual pdf file to bytebuffer and pass it to create a PDFFile object. But when i am attempting to do that i am facing illegalArgumentException:

```
public static void printpdf2(String filename) throws IOException, PrinterException{

    // Create a PDFFile from a File reference
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(bb);//Create PDF Print Page,exception here
    PDFPrintPage pages = new PDFPrintPage(pdfFile);

    // Create Print Job
    PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pf = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();
    pjob.setJobName(f.getName());
    Book book = new Book();
    book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
    pjob.setPageable(book);

    // Send print job to default printer
    pjob.print();
}
```

and this is the exception i receive:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.parseFile(PDFFile.java:1430)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:132)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:108)
at com.amin.PrintRepeatPDF.JPrintFile.printpdf2(JPrintFile.java:77)
at com.amin.PrintRepeatPDF.PrintFile.addTitlePage(PrintFile.java:136)
at com.amin.PrintRepeatPDF.PrintFile.print(PrintFile.java:65)
at com.amin.PrintRepeatPDF.ThreadedAction.run(ThreadedAction.java:79)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the method printpdf2 is called from JPrintFile.java line 77. before that its just called from couple of other classes in the hierarchy.

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: post the exact error message as it appears.

Comment: I'm no java expert, but it seems that you are trying to load a non-existent file.

Comment: The method takes the name of the .pdf file and then creates a File object from it, so i dont know if loading a non-existent file is the case here.

Comment: The exception sounds like it is about accessing a position in the file which is illegal, i.e. before the start or after the end. This might indicate a broken PDF. Can you share it for inspection?